# Using JavaScript RegEx to split & clean up HTML5 DB column name-attribute pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm RegEx illiterate. Matter of fact, RegEx gives me hives.

I need to split the following string at the 1st space and trim both sides of the output.

```
"id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" <-- 2 spaces between "id" and "INTEGER"
```

should become

```
["id", "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"]
```

Can any of the RegEx gurus help?

**Update after Kai's response**
There can be 1 to n number of spaces between the column name and the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\w+)\s+(.+)
```

To test http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 0):

Is it always two spaces only at the beginning? In that case, you can split using two spaces.

```
"id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT".split("  ");
```

**Edited response after updated question:**

```
var str = "id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",

    // Regex, very specific to your string, case-sensitive
    regex1 = /(id)\s+(INTEGER\sPRIMARY\sKEY\sAUTOINCREMENT)/,

    // Regex, not specific to your string, but follows pattern
    // and case-insensitive (/i). Same as zawhtut's response
    regex2 = /(\w+)\s+(.+)/i,

    results1 = str.match(regex1),

    results2 = str.match(regex2);


// Test (0th position is str, results start at 1)
alert(results1[1]); // id
alert(results1[2]); // INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

alert(results2[1]); // id
alert(results2[2]); // INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Comment: No, it could be any number of spaces or only one. That's why I'd like to trim after the column name is split from the attributes.

Comment: @DataZombies Wrong, it only splits after two consecutive spaces, so you'd get `[id, INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT]`. Give it a try. :)